# Problem with References in perl

Tags: perl, hash

Please I have a problem understanding references in perl . Can anyone provide a good explanation with an easy to follow examples. I am trying to understand how to precisely apply this concept to do hashes of hashes, hashes of array .

Edit
I have tried camel book but I cannot wrap my head around it.
The perlref is of great help though thanks for the suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `perldoc perlref` or either of the Llama (http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Perl-5th-Randal-Schwartz/dp/0596520107/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309547180&sr=8-1) or Camel (http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Perl-3rd-Larry-Wall/dp/0596000278/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309547210&sr=8-1) books?  Without a more specific question, you're unlikely to get a more helpful answer.

Comment: perldoc perlreftut; perldoc perldsc; perldoc perllol

Comment: I know the question's closed, but here is how I would go about learning about references, in this order: (1)Learning Perl (O'Reilly), (2) perlreftut, (3) perlref, (4) perllol, (5) perldsc, (6) Intermediate Perl (O'Reilly).  If that doesn't do it for you, there's always 1980's style BASIC; devoid of references. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start reading the [Llama book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452) and yes refer [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/).